# Excel VBA:pivot to auto filter data based on input from other sheet

Tags: excel, vba

hope you are doing good..
I have a sheet with pivot(sheet 5) where I manually filter data w.r.t IDs. Now I have a Input sheet(Sheet1) column B(B2) where I have IDs which changes day to day.Pivot should read the IDs from input sheet(sheet1) column B2, ann filter the data..
Any help here will be greatly appreciated..

Comment: Please see [ask] and [reprex], and take the [tour].

Comment: Is your question how to make a filter in a pivot table? Please reword.

Comment: Nope.  I want to auto filter the data in pivot based on the values given in column B of Input sheet..